# Convolutional layer: does the filter convolves also trough the nlayers_in or it take all the dimensions?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, julia

In the leading DeepLearning libraries, does the filter (aka kernel or weight) in the convolutional layer convolves also across the "channel" dimension or does it take all the channels at once?
To make an example, if the input dimension is `(60,60,10)` (where the last dimension is often referred as "channels") and the desired output number of channels is 5, can the filter be `(5,5,5,5)` or should it be `(5,5,10,5)` instead ?

Answer (score 2):

It should be (5, 5, 10, 5). Conv2d operation is just like Linear if you ignore the spatial dimensions.

From TensorFlow documentation [[link]](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d):

> Given an input tensor of shape batch_shape + [in_height, in_width, in_channels] and a filter / kernel tensor of shape **[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]**, this op performs the following:
>
> 1. Flattens the filter to a 2-D matrix with shape [filter_height * filter_width * in_channels, output_channels].
> 2. Extracts image patches from the input tensor to form a virtual tensor of shape [batch, out_height, out_width, filter_height * filter_width * in_channels].
> 3. For each patch, right-multiplies the filter matrix and the image patch vector.

Answer (score 2):

It takes all channels at once, so 5×5×10×5 should be right.

```
julia> using Flux

julia> c = Conv((5,5), 10 => 5);  # make a layer, 10 channels to 5

julia> c.weight |> summary
"5×5×10×5 Array{Float32, 4}"

julia> c(randn(Float32, 60, 60, 10, 1)) |> summary  # check it works
"56×56×5×1 Array{Float32, 4}"

julia> Conv(rand(Float32, (5,5,5,5)))  # different weight size
Conv((5, 5), 5 => 5)  # 630 parameters
```